# Show that $\Big| \frac{\sin(z)}{z^2}\Big| \le e$ for $z = \cos\theta + i \sin\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm required to show that $\Big| \frac{\sin(z)}{z^2} \Big| \le e$, for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$ satisfying $z = \cos\theta + i \sin\theta$, for $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$. That is $|z| = 1$. But I actually don't see how to verify this.

It holds directly that $|z^2| = |z|^2 = 1$. So I have to show that

$$|\sin(z)| = |\sin(\cos\theta + i \sin\theta)| \le e$$

For this, we remember that $\sin(x, y)$ can be expressed as

$$\psi(x, y) = \frac{1}{2} \Big( \sin(x)(e^{-y} + e^{y}), -\cos(x)(e^{-y} - e^{y}) \Big)$$

but couldn't arrive to the desired result. I appreciate any help.

EDIT 1: We have that $|\psi(x, y)| \le e \Longleftrightarrow |\psi(x, y)|^2 \le e^2 \Longleftrightarrow 4|\psi(x, y)|^2 \le 4e^2$ if and only if
$$e^{-2y} + e^{2y} + 2(\sin^2(x) - \cos^2(x)) \le 4e^2$$

Comment: Can you see that $|\sin z| \le \cosh |z|$?

Comment: @Gary Thanks mate! I saw it!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a boring way to do it.
$$|\sin(z)| = |\frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i}| = \left| \frac{e^{i\cos\theta -\sin\theta} - e^{-i\cos\theta +\sin\theta}}{2}\right| = \frac{1}{2}|e^{-\sin\theta}(\cos\cos\theta +i\sin\cos\theta) - e^{\sin\theta}(\cos\cos\theta -i\sin\cos\theta)| = \frac{1}{2}|(e^{-\sin\theta}- e^{\sin\theta})\cos\cos\theta + i(e^{-\sin\theta}+e^{\sin\theta})\sin\cos\theta)| = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{e^{-2\sin\theta}+e^{2\sin\theta} - 2\cos^2\cos\theta + 2\sin^2\cos\theta} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{e^{-2\sin\theta}+e^{2\sin\theta} - 2\cos^2\cos\theta + 2\sin^2\cos\theta} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2\cosh(2\sin\theta) - 2\cos(2\cos\theta)}$$
First, let us note that $2\cos(2\cos\theta) \leq 2$, thus
$$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2\cosh(2\sin\theta) - 2\cos(2\cos\theta)}\leq \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2\cosh2\sin\theta +2}.$$
Second, we note that $|\sin\theta| \leq 1$, thus $\cosh(2\sin\theta)$ achives its maximum at $|\sin\theta| = 1$. Thus,
$$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2\cosh(2\sin\theta) - 2\cos(2\cos\theta)}\leq \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{e^{2} + e^{-2} +2}.$$
Lastly, $e^{-2} +2 < e < e^2$. Hence,
$$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2\cosh(2\sin\theta) - 2\cos(2\cos\theta)}\leq \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{e^{2} + e^{-2} +2}\leq \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{e^{2} + e^{2}} = e.$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Although it is tedious, I envy your math-sight of using complex numbers and trigonometry. Actually, it is a very philosophically question: how big are trigonometric functions and complex numbers related... (Thanks for your answer!).